# Python Linux - Is-Alive Midori Watchdog

Tags: python, linux, midori

I am trying to implement a watchdog that will ping a host, if it is up then it will get midori to open the remote page, if not, then it will open a local page.

I have adapted this from the code here: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/6981/auto-refresh-for-midori.

The problem is it only appears to work once for each condition, for example, if the remote site is up, then the remote page is shown, when it goes down, the local page is shown, but when the remote goes up again, midori does not load the page.

I have disabled the midori calls and just outputted the up and last vars, and they are correct and the if conditions are executing correctly, so it looks like it is related to the popen and sub.calls.

Any ideas on what the issue may be ??

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
host = "localhost"
port = 888
recheck_time = 10
page_to_open_to = "/"
lurl = "///usr/share/scripts/splash.htm"
last = -1 #undefined state
up = -1 #Undefined state

import subprocess as sub
from time import sleep
import socket
import threading

sub.Popen(["midori", "-a","localhost:888","-e","Fullscreen"]) #open midori

#Check if internet is up
addr = (host, port) #the connection addr

while True:
    last = up #reset checking var
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) #create socket
    try: #attempt to ping, change vars
        s.connect(addr)
        up = 1

    except socket.error:
        up = 0 

    if up == 1 and last == 0:
        sub.call(["midori", "-a", "localhost:888","-e","Fullscreen"])
        print('up')

    elif up == 0 and last == 1:
        sub.call(["midori", "-a",lurl,"-e","Fullscreen"])
        print("down")

    s.close()

    print(up,",",last)
    sleep(recheck_time)
```

it appears that each time sub.call() is made a new process starts untill there are 2 processes, then nothing:

```
root      3499  0.3  0.5  10792  5856 tty1     S    17:44   0:00 /usr/bin/python /usr/share/scripts/midori.py
root      3500  3.3  4.7 191620 48240 tty1     Sl   17:44   0:03 midori -a localhost:888 -e Fullscreen
root      3530  1.0  2.8 173732 28836 tty1     Sl   17:45   0:00 midori -a ///usr/share/scripts/splash.htm
```

Answer (score 0):

The [subprocess call](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call) waits for the command to be completed.

So it feels like the midori calls are not returning. What will the midori do when it's been called? Will it close automatically after some time and thus return the flow to the Python code?

Try to execute the:

```
sub.call(["midori", "-a", "localhost:888","-e","Fullscreen"])
```

within the Python interpreter and check if it's returning.

If it isn't returning you should give the [Popen](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor) from the subprocess module a try. Pack the midori stuff into a Popen construct, (maybe) wait for for some specific output and the end midori (or keep it alive if you can pass in new URLs to a running midori).

Comment: Thanks, I tried calling it from within the interpreter, looks like a new process gets started. If I call it again then nothing is returned.

Comment: Did you realized that in the given example only the -e parameter is passed to the subprocess call for midori? Maybe that makes a difference.